# How can I make my contract send out my tokens?

Tags: contract-development, tokens

I've been experimenting with some generic copy-paste codes on the Ropsten Test Net and I am able to create a token and have the creator receive all the tokens. However, when I try to buy these test tokens on a second account, the Ether is sent, and no tokens ever come back my way. I'm just wondering where I should be looking in the code for this function since nothing anywhere else online seems to have my answer.

Comment: Without looking at the contract's code it can be anything. Transaction failed, Transfer event not generated, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following conditions

1. You have default function as payable so that it accepts ETH
2. You have the buy/sell price in the token contract

Answer (score 0):

The crowdsale functionality can be separated from the token.

Suggest reading the OpenZeppelin documentation on creating tokens and crowdsales
https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/tokens
https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/crowdsales